# Passive voice reuse after "and" conjunction + screen/display usage

Tags: passive-voice

1 Should you copy passive voice frame if the verb has a pair connected with &?

2 Which is more preferable - screen or display in terms of colorless led surface of small smartwatches?

3 Is it possible to omit last "an"?

A full meal can take up to 10 hours **to get digested** by your body & **show up** on smartband **screen** as intake

A full meal can take up to 10 hours **to get digested** by your body & **to be shown up** on smartband **display** as **an** intake

Comment: Questions 1 and 2 are incomprehensible. You can, however, omit the final _an_; it's optional.

Answer (score 1):

I would go with:

> A full meal can take up to 10 hours to be digested by your body and show up on your smartband display as an intake.

But that's just me.

Comment: could you please describe - why?
As for me, it reads as if the meal would show up by itself, not be shown up (by something)

Comment: Think about the construction of the sentence itself, both grammatically and logically: the subject of the sentence is *a full meal*, which first can take up to 10 hours to be digested by your body, and once this has occurred, that same meal will show up on your smartband display as an input. The construction I've suggested is the simplest, straighforward English expression of what you are trying to communicate, assuming this is either UI text or explanatory technical writing we're discussing.

Comment: If you don't *actually* ***need*** to specify that final descriptor, in fact the simplest, cleanest version would be: ***A full meal can take up to 10 hours to be digested by your body and show up on your smartband display.***

Comment: thank you, all that i wanted to point out is could you actually say that meal will show up? Because in many languages the actor couldn't be an object, only a person or other living essence

Maybe, i'm just missing smth about "show up" phrase? Is it passive already?

Comment: yes, in English you can say that the meal will show up - English definitely allows for inanimate subjects using active verbs: "a rock showed up in my shoe"; "that stapler just showed up on my desk; I've no idea who put it there"; "the chair I was sitting in disappeared when I stood up" all work grammatically.